# Use single completion handler Globally

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I have a my custom alert controller with only three buttons and I have three buttons **Cancel** , **Send** , **Add** but I want to have a single completion handler like below.

```
self.showAlertWithButtonClicked(clickedButton: { (clickedButton) -> Void in
        //check the button index by clickedButton.tag

        })
```

But when I tried to implement this into my AlertController class, it doesn't allow me.
Below is my MyAlertController WireFrame code:

```
class MyAlertController: UIViewController {


typealias CompletionHandler = (_ clickedButton: UIButton) -> Void
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func showAlertWithButtonClicked(clickedButton: @escaping (MultipleMethodRunningHandle)) {
    //Do what you want

}

func pressedCancelButton(button: UIButton) {
    //At this point compiler doesn't allow me to use that completionHandler globally in the class
    button.tag = 0
    clickedButton(button)
}
func pressedSendButton(button: UIButton) {
    //At this point compiler doesn't allow me to use that completionHandler globally in the class
    button.tag = 1
    clickedButton(button)
}
func pressedAddButton(button: UIButton) {
    //At this point compiler doesn't allow me to use that completionHandler globally in the class
    button.tag = 2
    clickedButton(button)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

How can I achieve this so that I can access those handlers in the entire class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply paste my code.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Touristan
//
//  Created by Syed Qamar Abbas on 21/01/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Syed Qamar Abbas. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

typealias MultipleMethodRunningHandle = (_ clickedButton: UIButton) -> Void

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var buttonClicked: MultipleMethodRunningHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func showAlertWithButtonClicked(clickedButton: @escaping (MultipleMethodRunningHandle)) {
        //Do what you want
        self.buttonClicked = clickedButton
    }

    func pressedCancelButton(button: UIButton) {
        //Do what you want
        button.tag = 0
        self.buttonClicked!(button)
    }

    func pressedSendButton(button: UIButton) {
        //Do what you want
        button.tag = 1
        self.buttonClicked!(button)
    }

    func pressedAddButton(button: UIButton) {
        //Do what you want
        button.tag = 2
        self.buttonClicked!(button)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```